# Should I reference a state value while setting another state in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose I have two states, one which updates and holds the value of an `<input>` field and other is an array which collects the value. Should I use the former state value to set the later?

```
const [text, setText] = useState('')
const [textArr, setTextArr] = useState([])

const onChangeTextHandler = (value) => {
  setText(value)
}

const onSubmitHandler = () => {
  setTextArr((prevArr) => [...prevArr, text])
}
```

As stated, the `onSubmitHandler` updates it's state based on the value of the `<input>`. Is this correct? If not what's the alternative?

Comment: Do you want to create an array of all the words typed in the input of the letters typed?

Comment: Yes, sure is it the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");
const [textArr, setTextArr] = useState([]);
// textArr will have the array

const onChangeTextHandler = (e) => {
  if (e.target.value.contains(" ")) {
    //add to array when a space is added to text and start another word
    submitToArray(e.target.value);
    setText("");
  } else {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }
};

const submitToArray = (value) => {
  setTextArr([...textArr, value]);
};

...

<form name="myForm">
  <input name="names" type="text" value={text} onChange={onChangeTextHandler} />
</form>;
```

or this

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");
let wordsArr = [];
// wordsArr will have the array

const onChangeTextHandler = (e) => {
  if (e.target.value.contains(" ")) {
    //add to array when a space is added to text and start another word
    submitToArray(e.target.value);
    setText("");
  } else {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }
};

const submitToArray = (value) => {
  wordsArr.push(value);
};

...

<form name="myForm">
  <input name="names" type="text" value={text} onChange={onChangeTextHandler} />
</form>;
```